# hide images without src

Tags: jquery

Im generating my page content on the serverside and sometimes as reault I have an image without src. Is it possible to hide all such images using jquery so that ugly icons arent visible for example in chrome ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are **not supposed to have any `<img/>` tags without a `src` attribute!**

But you can use `$('img:not([src]), img[src=""]')` to select images with empty or missing `src` attrs.

Comment: Using same selectors in CSS 3 can provide same effect by adding display:none;

Comment: For some lazyloading, there will be a brief time where an image is using a data-src and needs to be hidden until loaded.

Comment: @ChristopheCVB Thanks for your comment. That was a much cleaner implementation for my use case instead of using JS.

Answer (score 1):

More complete answer derived from ThiefMaster would be on the following lines

```
$.each($('img:not([src]), img[src=""]'),function(index, value) { 
 value.css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Why not use the proper `$(selector).each(function() { /*use this here */ })` syntax? `$.each()` is meant to be used on arbitrary (non-jquery) collections.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using JavaScript to hide errors in your markup. Consider people who run with JavaScript disabled, or who use a screen reader.

You don't mention what you're using on the server-side, but surely it's pretty simple in any language to surround the code that outputs the `<img>` tag with an IF statement to check if the `src` value is blank.